# Integral of $e^{x^3+x^2-1}(3x^4+2x^3+2x)$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, problem-solving

I understand that this looks exactly like a "Do my Homework" kinda question but trust me, I've spent hours(I won't go into detail as it's off topic).
**Note:** I'm a High School student, our teacher gave this question as a challenge.

I'm struggling with

> $$\int e^{x^3+x^2-1}(3x^4+2x^3+2x)\ dx$$

**My Progress:** I tried finding integral by parts, and found that$$\int e^{x^3+x^2-1}\ dx$$

was the only trouble maker(for now).
So, I tried finding it's integral then gave up and tried using a calculator to see what I missed.
The website said: That it's antiderivative is not *elementary*. I didn't even know what that means.

**New Approach:** Now, I went on to trying to plot the graph of $$ e^{x^3+x^2-1}$$  to see if I could related it to $$\int_{-a}^x e^{x^3+x^2-1}\ dx$$ and say whether $$\int e^{x^3+x^2-1}\ dx$$ exists or not.

 *I was hoping for some discontinuity in the graph of the definite integral but I didn't seem to find any.*

**Note:** I drew the graph of the definite integral through observation and intuition, I don't think there was any other method.

So is there anyway of helping me?

Comment: differentiate $$x^2e^{x^3+x^2-1}+C$$ with respect to $x$

Comment: It's a challenge to you. If you have read any answer here, you have failed the challenge. However your knowledge has improved.

Comment: @user1952500 Oh crap! You know what I'm not gonna scroll any further. I understand what you mean. It would be far more better for my mind to try my best and only keep these answers as the last option. **I'm so sorry everyone who answered, I'll read the post again within a week and mark the answered that helped the most** THANKS EVERYONE!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can go ahead with integration by parts but taking some time for careful inspection can lead you to a quick answer.

> $$\int e^{\color{blue}{x^3+x^2-1}}(3x^4+2x^3+2x)\ dx$$

Notice that $\color{blue}{\left( x^3+x^2-1 \right)}' = \color{red}{3x^2+2x}$ and that $3x^4+2x^3 = x^2 \color{red}{\left( 3x^2+2x \right)}$, so you have:

$$\begin{align}
\left(3x^4+2x^3+2x\right)e^{x^3+x^2-1} &
 = x^2\color{red}{\left( 3x^2+2x \right)}e^{\color{blue}{x^3+x^2-1}}+\color{green}{2x}e^{x^3+x^2-1} \\[6pt]
& = x^2\color{blue}{\left( x^3+x^2-1 \right)}'e^{\color{blue}{x^3+x^2-1}}+\color{green}{\left( x^2 \right)'}e^{x^3+x^2-1} \\[6pt]
& = x^2\color{blue}{\left(e^{\color{blue}{x^3+x^2-1}} \right)}'+\color{green}{\left( x^2 \right)'}e^{x^3+x^2-1} \\[6pt]
& = \left( x^2e^{x^3+x^2-1} \right)'
\end{align}$$
where you recognize the product rule for derivatives in the last step.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Try to find a primitive of the form $\exp(x^3+x^2-1)Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the solution to be of the form $\exp(x^3+x^2-1)Q(x)$ and differentiate this expression to get $\exp(x^3+x^2-1)\left[(3x^2+2x)Q(x)+Q'(x)\right]$. Compare this with $\exp(x^3+x^2-1)\left[3x^4+2x^3+2x\right]$ to obtain the ODE:

$$(3x^2+2x)Q(x)+Q'(x)=3x^4+2x^3+2x.$$

The particular solution is $x^2$, you could also solve this ODE with separation of variables and variation of parameters to get $$Q(x)=x^2+c_1\exp(-x^3-x^2).$$ Setting $c_1=0$ will result in the particular solution $x^2$.

So, the integral is given by $\exp(x^3+x^2-1)x^2+c$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I = \int e^{x^3+x^2-1}\bigg(3x^4+2x^3+2x\bigg)dx = \int e^{x^3+x^2-1}\cdot x^2\bigg(3x^2+2x+2x^{-1}\bigg)dx$$

So $$I = \int e^{x^3+x^2+2\ln x-1}\bigg(3x^2+2x+2x^{-1}\bigg)dx$$

Put $x^3+x^2+2\ln x-1 = t\;,$ Then $(3x^2+2x+2x^{-1})dx = dt$

So $$I = \int e^t dt = e^t+\mathcal{C} = e^{x^3+x^2+2\ln x-1}+\mathcal{C} = x^2\cdot e^{x^3+x^2-1}+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we would like to have in our integral something like the derivative of $x^3-x^2-1$, which is $3x^2+2x$. So, let us just divide $3x^4+2x^3+2x$ by $3x^2+2x$. We will get:
$$3x^4+2x^3+2x=x^2(3x^2+2x)+2x$$
So, let's plug it in our integral:
$$\begin{align*}\int e^{x^3+x^2-1}(3x^4+2x^3+2x)dx=&\int e^{x^3+x^2-1}\left(x^2(3x^2+2x)+2x\right)dx=\\
=&\int x^2e^{x^3+x^2-1}(3x^2+2x)+2xe^{x^3+x^2-1}dx=\\
=&\int x^2\left(e^{x^3+x^2-1}\right)'+(x^2)'e^{x^3+x^2-1}dx=\\
=&\int \left(x^2e^{x^3+x^2-1}\right)'dx=\\
=&x^2e^{x^3+x^2-1}+c,\ c\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}$$

Hope this helped! :)